# Finding constraints in inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, string, constrained-dynamics

So, I've been having doubts about finding constraint equations for a disk of radius $R$ and mass $M$ rolling (frictionless) in a inclined plane, connected through a rope to a rectangular block of mass $m$:

[image]

Taking my coordinates to be the azimuthal angle $\phi$ for the sphere and the displacement $\xi$ along the inclined plane, we could have the constraint:
\begin{equation}f(\xi,\phi)=\xi-R\phi\end{equation}
$L$ being the length of the rope. I would then write the transformations as:
\begin{align}&x=\xi\cos\alpha+R\sin\phi\
&y=-\xi\sin\phi-R\sin\alpha\end{align}
But, in the constraints, shouldn't I have taken into account the constant lenght of the rope? Therefore I'd have, for a vertical portion $h$ of the length:

\begin{equation}g(\xi,h)=\xi+h-L\end{equation}

But I haven't taken $h$ as a coordinate, and I don't know if it's benefitial, doing so. How would I write the Lagrangian then?

Any help will be appreciated.